# Логин в sqlcmd через jenkins использую Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, jenkins

Я настраиваю CI. Настраиваю через jenkins pipline. Мне нужно запускать sql скрипт в ms sql. Использую я для этого sqlcmd команду которую прописываю в jenkinsfile. Вот так выглядит команда bat

```
sqlcmd -e -S \"someserver\" -i \"D:\\somefile.sql\" -E
```

В данной команде -E говорит, что для логина в sql server нужно использовать windows authentication, т.к я запускаю это на сервере должно работать(но пока я тестирую локально), это нужно для того что бы не хранить credentials от бд в репозитории (jenkinsfile лежит в репозитории). Когда в jenkins запускаю билд получаю вот такое сообщение

> The server principal "CS\xxxxxxxx$" is not able to access the database
>   "xxxx" under the current security context.

Я так понимаю через jenkins я не могу воспользоваться windows authentication т.е если запустить эту команду через командную строку, то тогда мой sql скрипт выполняется.

Comment: пользователь, от имени которого запускается скрипт, есть в БД?

Comment: @Anatol скрипт запускается дженкинсом автоматически когда происходит деплой в определенную ветку

Comment: Дайте права на базу"хххх" principal-у "CS\xxxxxxxx$"

Comment: @Denis Rubashkin права у этого пользователя то есть проблема видимо в контексте under the current security context и если я правильно понимаю под контекстом имеется ввиду jenkins

Comment: А в "пользователях" этой конкретной базы этот пользователь нормально отображен? Без каких-нибудь красных стрелочек/квадратиков и тп?

Comment: @DenisRubashkin да все нормально, я кстати уже давно разобрался и дал ответ, так что если интересно, можете посмотреть)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я уже давно решил эту проблем, хочу поделиться решением. Jenkins запускается как Windows Service поэтому нужно выставить ему права пользователя который имеет доступ к базе и тогда вам будет доступна windows authentication. Надеюсь это кому-нибудь поможет)